# Dll compilation with Cmake

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake

I am currently trying to compile dll on windows with cmake and MinGW (x64), but i would like 
to statically linking the c++ runtime to my dll in order to deploy my dll without adding the c++ ones.

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc ")

project(Comp)

set (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)

include (GenerateExportHeader)

FIND_PACKAGE(ITK)

IF(ITK_FOUND)
  INCLUDE(${ITK_USE_FILE})
ELSE(ITK_FOUND)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR <<ITK not found.>>)
ENDIF(ITK_FOUND)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${ITK_LIBRARY_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${ITK_LIBRARY_DIRS})

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories($ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include)
include_directories($ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/win32)

add_library(mylib SHARED source/mysources.cxx)

target_link_libraries(mylib ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

But when i check the generated dll file, there are still dependencies against dlls in my MinGw folder.
How configure CMakeLists.txt to get rid of the dependencies espacialy libstc++-6.dll and  libgcc_s_seh-1.dll ?

Best regards

Comment: I think in this case you need to build static version of `libgcc` and `libstd`

Comment: Hi, actually i already have the .a version of those files but nothing seems to append when i try to link them against my lib